# Tool for extracting text patterns with Regular Expression?

Tags: gratis, regex

Is there a good and cost-free tool for **extracting text**, using Regular Expressions? I'm using OS X.

I know that there are online tools for "testing" Regex patterns – like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) – but I'm looking for a tool that can actually help me extract multi-line text using a pattern.

I have a few thousand lines of text from which I need to extract snippets from every line.

If there are multiple alternatives, I would like to know if there's any one in particular that I should know about.

Comment: Why a web-based tool? Wouldn't a local tool be faster for a few thousand lines? We're not recommending websites, so answers that you'll get are web-based tools that you install on your own server and then use the web-based tool.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Just because it's more practical if there's something I can use in a web browser, without having to install anything. But if you know anything for OS X, I'm interested.

Comment: What's your budget requirement?

Comment: Okay, I will update my question. I'm looking for a free solution.

Comment: Free as in "free beer" (no money) – or as in "free speech" (open source)?

Comment: "Cost-free" please, see the edited question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You Already Have

OS-X comes with [python](http://python.org) installed, *if not it is a free download*, and python comes with the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library installed by default, which is one of the best regular expression libraries that I have found, what I especially like is that you can put comments into your regular expressions.

OS-X also comes with `grep` & `sed` installed which can both operate with regular expressions.

### You Can Install

If you really must work in the browser then [ipython](http://ipython.org/) & [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) notebooks is a way to go *not sure if it is installed by default* but it is easy to install.

### On the Web

You can even try ipython/Jupyter out in your browser [here](https://try.jupyter.org/) without installing anything.

### Freedom

All of the above are free both gratis and Open Source with the possible exception of the OS/X implementations of grep & sed.

### Other Platforms

grep and sed are available on most *nix platforms, i.e. OS/X, Linux, etc., but not by default on Windows, *there are free packages available that do add them though, e.g. msys.*

Python/iPython/Jupyter are available for just about every platform from RaspberryPy to Supercomputers and just about everything in between including OS/X, Linux & Windows.

Answer (score 2):

### You already have… grep and sed

If you’re okay with [POSIX regular expressions](https://www.mirbsd.org/man7/re_format), every unixoid system comes with [grep](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/grep) and [sed](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/sed).

Extract matching lines:

```
grep 'pattern' file
```

Extract matches:

```
sed -n '/^.*\(pattern\).*$/s//\1/p' file
```

This gets a little more complicated, so create a script for it:

```
#!/bin/sh
pattern=$1
shift
sed -n '/^.*\('"$pattern"'\).*$/s//\1/p' "$@"
```

### You already have… Perl

Most regular expressions examples use [perlre](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/perlre) or PCRE, which are somewhat compatible, instead (if you use things like `\s`, this is true for you). The [Perl Regular Expressions Tutorial](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/perlretut.htm) already contains a “simple_grep” which can do the extraction à la grep, although you can do it inline too:

```
perl -ne 'print if /pattern/;' file
```

Or just the matches (explicit newline there):

```
perl -ne 'print $&.$/ if /pattern/;' file
```

You could also do multi-line matches instead of pulling out lines, or extract multiple matches from each line; this depends on your requirements, which aren’t clear enough.